# Solving for a variable with square roots in equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm working on the following equation:

$$ a= \frac{2}{t^2}[(d+l)^{1/2} - (d^{1/2})]^2 $$

I want to solve for l such that:

$$ l=\frac{1}{2}at^2+(\sqrt{2ad}) t $$

I can't get it in this form. Here's my attempt:

$$ \frac{at^2}{2} = [(d+l)^{1/2} - (d^{1/2})]^2 $$
$$ \sqrt{\frac{at^2}{2}} = [(d+l)^{1/2} - (d^{1/2})] $$
$$ \sqrt{\frac{at^2}{2}} + d^{1/2} = [d+l]^{1/2}  $$
$$ (\sqrt{\frac{at^2}{2}} + d^{1/2})^2 = [d+l]  $$
$$ (\frac{at^2}{2} + 2\sqrt{\frac{dat^2}{2}} + d = [d+l]  $$
$$ \frac{at^2}{2} + 2\sqrt{\frac{dat^2}{2}} = l  $$
$$ \frac{at^2}{2} + 2t\sqrt{\frac{da}{2}} = l  $$

This of course isn't in the form I'm looking for. The first piece $\frac{at^2}{2} $is good, but the second piece $ 2t\sqrt{\frac{da}{2}}$ does not equal $\sqrt{2ad}t$

Surely I must be making a mistake somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Umm..actually you answered it yourself.  Take the  $2$ inside the square root and it becomes $4$ and then cancels out with the $2$ in the denominator.

Comment: I think I must have forgotten about this rule you are talking about. Can you show me an example of 'taking 2 inside the square root'?

Comment: $$2t\sqrt{\frac{da}{2}}$$ $$=t\sqrt{2^2\frac{da}{2}}$$ $$=t\sqrt{4\frac{da}{2}}$$ $$=t\sqrt{2da}$$